# creating multi-line tableau charts

Tags: charts, tableau-api

I am trying to create a visualization of product build times over the year.

what I want to see, at the lowest level of the hierarchy,  is for each job, the main/max/avg/mean/std dev as wavy lines over time.

my database has job name, date/time, status, and duration
the job name has a structure to it, so I would like to take the 1st 3 chars and build a hierarchy.  the second set of 3 chars defines the 'product group'

so I would like to see these 5 lines for product group, drill in to product team, drill in to job, across the 365 days of the rolling timescale we collect data for (1 year).

I can get, for each 'job', a pane that shows max, or min, or avg, as lines, but I cannot get them together in the same chart.. 
start date as column, job name, max/avg/min/std as row elements

for the hierarchy, it looks like I have to place that data in the data source to be able to use it. I cannot find a way to define a hierarchy based on part of existing data

Comment: Drag "Measure Values" to the worksheet. A box of measures will appear on the side, select the ones you want to display. Or try the "Show me" menu, there you can find the chart that combine lines in the same chart

Comment: thanks.. I had that manually, but not by dragging the values to the sheet.  I think my problem might be that I have very sparse data at the moment, so I see max/avg/min as a single dot, and a lot of whitepace where there is nothing in the database   Is there a way to make the line chart use the last known value as it progresses to not have empty spaces?

Comment: You can configure the Tableau formatting for a field to specify how to handle special (e.g. NULL) values. Click on a measure field on your worksheet, say MAX(Build_Time), select format, and look at the bottom option for Special Values, Marks: Try the different options. You can then pick a different field at the top right of the format pane and format that one if desired. Also, a shortcut for dragging measure values to the Columns shelf is to first plot one measure, and then drag a second to the same axis (e.g., column axis on the left margin)